# SSDT - How to: Incremental Updates?

Tags: sql-server, database, version-control, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using the Database project in Visual Studio.

In my scenario I have several customers using different versions of the database.

For example, a customer who is in version 5 and another in version 7.

I make available an update to version 8.

The client version 5 should run the "cumulative" scripts (that update to version 6 and 7) before running the script that updates to version 8.

The client version 7 should run just what upgrade to version 8.

**Is there any automatic way to do that today with the SSDT?**

Comment: Are you looking for an automated Build or a Publish from within VS?

Comment: I'am looking for Publish, SAS

Comment: Great, then use the argument GetVersion (if version 8 is not the latest checked in your example). Deploy using msbuild, or using the dacpac from your build, as I described in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With msbuild: /p:GetVersion=CXXXX

Form VS, get the specific version (right-click the Project in Solution Explorer) Before publishing.

You run this against the two different targets, and the publish scripts will be created for the specified target (one per target).

If you use a dacpac instead, the script is auto-generated at deploy-time from the dacpac, by comparing to the target. If yo want to deploy the same version you can use the same dacpac file on both targets, the generated script will be created specifically for each target.

Comment: If this works it will be wonderful!

So I can use a single dacpac (result of my build) to update any client?

In this case, if I generate a dacpac version 8, and run it on the client version 5, which have not yet upgraded to version 6 and not 7, will work?

Comment: Yes! One file to multiple targets (containíng different versions). The scripts are created at deploy-time. If you are updating to a production server it is a good idea to generate and Review the script Before deploying it, especially if it is online during the deployment, since some changes might affect performance and lock tables..

Comment: Also, if you have any manually created scripts that are included as pre/post-scripts, they must work correclty on both target version.

Answer (score 3):

The concept of deploying cumulative "versions" of a database goes away when using SSDT (in my opinion). The fundamental concept of SSDT that one *must* understand is that of declarative database development. My personal definition of declarative database development:

You define what state you want your database schema to be in, not how to get it into that state. The publishing engine within SSDT will take care of getting your database into that state.

Simple example, you currently have a table in your database called [Person] and you want to add a column called [Person].[MiddleName]. You define that new column in SSDT and when you publish, SSDT will issue something akin to the following:

```
ALTER TABLE [Person] ADD COLUMN [MiddleName]
```

The point is that you don't have to write that SQL statement, SSDT writes and executes it for you.
In this scenario the concept of database versions goes away. You're only ever updating your database to the state as defined in your SSDT project. Hope that helps.

Comment: This tool is just awesome. Thank you for reply.

Comment: What about situations in which the delta script cannot automatically be inferred, or if custom steps are needed? What is available in the SSDT workflow to handle these scenarios? (For example: A non-nullable column needs to be added to a table with existing records, and the column value must be populated with the result of a custom function). If SSDT is generating the delta script to modify multiple DB objects in a given sequence, how would one inject and modify custom steps in the generated script?

Comment: @cvacca you make an excellent point. The deployment will simply error if it detects any breaking changes. (i.e. detects data loss). There are some migration steps that just can't be automatically generated

Answer (score 1):

You should supply the dacpac which is the output to the build and then give them that to deploy.

You can deploy it manually through SSMS or you can give them a command line that runs sqlpackage.exe - this can either perform the update or just generate a script that upgrades their database.

Comment: If this works it will be wonderful!

So I can use a single dacpac (result of my build) to update any client?

In this case, if I generate a dacpac version 8, and run it on the client version 5, which have not yet upgraded to version 6 and not 7, will work?

Comment: yes that is how it is supposed to work - the only thing to be careful of is how you deal with breaking changes like splitting tables and any scripts for reference data

Comment: I second what @EdElliott says, test your deployments against a copy of production first. Its always possible that you've done something that might cause a deployment failure (e.g. removing a column). By default SSDt will do anything destruvtive to your database, it will just throw an error instead, but its still good to know in advance that an error might occur.